# Jest and Enzyme Test Functional Component: Method that returns JSX

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Having troubles displaying JSX returned from method.

Error I get is `Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.`

When I run `wrapper.debug()` no JSX elements from the condition exists. (I can hit the console.log in that method though)

Thank you in advance!!

```
component.js

function component(props) {
   const [message, setMessage] = useState();
   const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      fetch.then((results)=>(setMessage(fetchedMessage));
   });

   const displayMessage = () => {
      if(condition1) {
         return(
            <div class="container">
               <div id='user'>
                  Hello user, {message}
                  {console.log("test if I am hitting inside this statement")} 
               </div>
            </div>
         )
      };
      if(condition2) {
         return(
            <div class="container">
               <div id='admin'>Hello admin, {message}</div>
               <button id='modal-button' onClick={() => {setOpen(true}}> Open </button>
            </div>
         )
      };
      return null;
   };

   return (
      <>
      <div>{message ? displayMessage() : null}</div>
      <Modal open={open} />
      </>
   );
};
```

```
component.spec.js

describe('Describe test', () => {
   function createMockStore() {
      return configureMockStore()({ mockedStore: {some values}})
   };

   it('displays correct message for condition1', () => {
      const mockFetchedData = { message: "Mocked message" };

      const mockStore = createMockStore(condition1);

      const mockFetchData = jest.fn(() => new Promise((resolve) => resolve({ data: mockFetchedData })));

      const wrapper = await mount(
         <Provider store={mockStore}> 
            <Component {...props} /> 
         </Provider>
      ).find('Component');

      expect(wrapper.find('#user').text().toEqual("Mocked message"))); //Failing here. Error is: Method “text” is meant to be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
   });
};
```

Comment: It's not evident that console.log has been called at the time of assertion. You can be sure it wasn't. `await` for a promise that mockFetchData returns before asserting.